# Whiptail gauge for any number of shell commands

Tags: bash, shell

This is what I have so far and it works in the sense that it give a gauge and I can pass it as many commands as I want. The problem is the `$COMMAND` never actually executes on the shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

progressBar() {
  declare TODO=("${@}")
  NUM_TODO=${#TODO[*]}
  STEP=$((100/NUM_TODO))
  IDX=0
  COUNTER=0
  (
  while :
  do
    cat <<EOF
XXX
$COUNTER
${TODO[$IDX]}
XXX
EOF
    COMMAND="${TODO[$IDX]} &>/dev/null"
    [[ $NUM_TODO -lt $IDX ]] && $COMMAND
    (( IDX+=1 ))
    (( COUNTER+=STEP ))
    [ $COUNTER -gt 100 ] && break
    sleep 1
  done
  ) |
  whiptail --title "Please wait..." --gauge "Please wait..." 6 70 0
}

progressBar \
  "touch bla" \
  "cp bla bla-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.backup"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [[ $NUM_TODO -lt $IDX ]] is round the wrong way, should be $IDX -lt $NUM_TODO.

Comment: oh god... Thats what happens when you stare at a problem for to long...

Comment: Been there too :)